# Атрибуты одного класса в другом

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как мне получить атрибуты(переменные-члены) одного класса внутри другого класса?
Объект создать не могу: это работа с графическим интерфейсом и при создании объекта одного класса внутри другого, вызывается конструктор - создаются окна этого класса.

Comment: Пусть класс А - это класс к атрибутам которого вы хотите иметь доступ, а класс В - тот, откуда хотите вызывать. Добавьте в класс В атрибут и сохраняйте туда объект класса А. Можно через конструктор, можно через отдельный `set`-метод. А потом обращайтесь к этому полю как к своему `self.class_A_object.position`.

Comment: Объект создать не могу: это работа с графическим интерфейсом и при создании объекта одного класса внутри другого, вызывается конструктор - создаются окна этого класса.

Comment: а уже существующий объект передать нельзя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `Top` наследует текст из `lable` класса `Main` в свой `label_top`

```
import tkinter as tk


class Top(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, top_main, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main = top_main
        self.label_top = tk.Label(self, text=self.main.label['text'])
        self.label_top.grid()


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label = tk.Label(text='что то с чем то ')
        self.label.grid()
        self.a = tk.Button(text='нажми', command=self.top).grid()

    def top(self):
        self.f = Top(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятна проблема. Для того чтобы Вам предложили решение - нужно конкретнее что вы хотите получить. Из того что я вижу в написанном могу предложить попробовать наследование. У класса-наследника есть доступ к атрибутам класса-родителя.

```
class A:
    arg_a1 = 3
    arb_a2 = 5

class B(A):
    arg_b1 = 6

print(B.arg_a1)
```